# $on event callback parameters

Tags: angularjs

In my .run function I have something like:

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(event, args){...})
```

(Angular ver 1.2.10)

[edit]
Where in the documentation can I find out what is passed for args for the event $routeChangeSuccess?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this page in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24emit).

Whatever `args` are passed to `$emit(name, args)` or `$broadcast(name, args)` will be available to `$on(name, function(event, args) {});`

Comment: This doesn't tell me what is passed in the case of $routeChangeSuccess?

Answer (score 3):

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(event, args){
    debugger;
});
```

Debugger will automatically open the developer tools, you can now inspect your passed arguments inside the developer tools.

or just do a `console.log` and check your console output.

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(event, args){
    console.log(args);
});
```